# UITextField in Swift – text didSet not called when typing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield, didset

I am writing a custom UITextField right now in Swift, and encountered the following:

```
class MyField: UITextField {
    
    open override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            // some logic that normalizes the text
        }
    }

    private func setup() { //called on init
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(textEditingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func textEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    }
}
```

Now, when testing this, I observed that, when the user is typing something, `textEditingChanged` is called, but `text.didSet` is not. Neither is `text.willSet`, for that matter. However, in `textEditingChanged`, the textfield's text will already be updated to the new value.

Can anyone explain what is going on here? Is Swift circumventing the setter on purpose? How am I supposed to know when/if the setter is called, is there any logic to this in UIKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text property of the `UITextField` is only for external use, when you are typing `UIKit` handles the update internally. Can't really tell whats going on under the hood, as we do not have access to `UIKit` implementation but one possible answer to the question is that `UITextField` is using an other internal variable for storing the text property. When you are getting the text property, you are actually getting that internal value, and when you are setting it, you are setting that internal value also. Of course under the hood it is a bit more complicated but it may look something like this(`SampleUITextField` represents the `UITextField`):

```
// This how the UITextField implementation may look like
class SampleUITextField {
    private var internalText: String = ""

    var text: String  {
        get {
            internalText
        } set {
            internalText = newValue
        }
    }

    // This method is just to demonstrate that when you update the internalText didSet is not called 
    func updateInternalTextWith(text: String) {
       internalText = text
    }
}
```

And when you subclass it it looks like:

```
class YourTextField: SampleUITextField {
    override var text: String {
        didSet {
            print("DidSet called")
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you set the text property directly the `didSet` is called because the `text` value updates. You can check it:

```
let someClass = YourTextField()
someClass.text = "Some new text"
// didSet is called
```

But now when you call `updateInternalTextWith` the `didSet` is not called:

```
let someClass = YourTextField()
someClass.updateInternalTextWith(text: "new text")
// didSet is not called
```

That's because you are not updating the text value directly, but just the internal text property. A similar method is called to update the internal text variable of the `UITextField` when you are typing, and that's the reason the `didSet` is not called in your case.

For that reason, it is not enough to override the `text` variable when we want to be notified when the text properties changes, and we need to use delegate(`UITextFieldDelegate`) methods or notifications (`textFieldDidChange`) to catch the actual change.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of formatting are you trying to perform on the UITextField?

Shouldn't it be the responsibility of a **ViewModel** (or any model managing the business logic for the view containing this text field) instead?

Also, you shouldn't use `didSet` to perform changes, its mainly here to allow you to respond to changes, not chain another change.

Comment: This is not an architectural question, the example given is merely to illustrate the problem. The question is: How is it possible that `text` changes on the textfield without `text.didSet` being called? (and maybe more imporantly, how am I as a programmer supposed to know when this is happening?)

Comment: Good point. Have you tried manually setting the value to see if it triggers the `didSet`?

Comment: yeah, `didSet` works except when the user is typing. It seems to me this is intended by UIKit, but I can't find any reference to this behaviour in the docs or anywhere.

Comment: Do you observe the same behaviour with KVO?

Comment: yes same behaviour with KVO. I think it's just something to "know and accept".

Comment: Another weird behavioural issue to keep somewhere in our dirty minds thanks to Apple :D